# "Moving to superuser" closure of threads

Tags: discussion

I've noticed this for a while, especially on StackOverflow - someone will ask a desktop/enduser related question and very quickly the question will get closed with a comment/resolution of 'Moved to SuperUser.com'.

For example - https://serverfault.com/questions/50122/107mb-s-network-file-copying-slowed-to-16-5mb-s-playing-local-media-files-wh

Whats the point in that?  SuperUser.com is in closed beta - I get a link to the SU question, but I cannot access it.  What happens with regard to the author?  Do they get an automated invite to SU?  Or do they simply lose access to their question?

People seem to be using SU as though it is open to the public, and moving stuff to it.  Sure, it might belong there, but if we cannot access it then why?

Comment: The password isn't a secret - it's actually pretty easy to find if you look http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/

Comment: "ewok.adventure" for those too lazy.

Comment: I'm too lazy to read TheTXI's comment. Can somebody hack into my computer and sign me up?

Comment: I'm too lazy to turn my computer on so somebody can hack into it.  Can someone create an account for me, read my thoughts, and post them?

Comment: I'm too lazy to think. That is all.

Comment: @TheTXI: You're also too ugly to look at, but that doesn't stop you from appearing in public.

Comment: I'm

Comment: I'm too lazy to stop appearing in public.

Comment: Has everyone forgotten how to use google or have they never known how?

Comment: I'm too lazy to use Google

Comment: @Kyle - thankyou, I wasn't even aware that there was a blog.

@TheTXI - it isn't a case of being too lazy, more of a case of not really knowing where to look.

@Troggy - why is this a 'jfgi' thing?  Did I do something wrong by asking about this on the meta.* side of these sites, since it *is* meta discussion.  To be honest, I don't think I would ever google 'superuser.com password' without first knowing that it was a 'nonpublic public' beta.  To all intent and purpose, the SU site makes it look like you have to be invited, not that the password is available on a blog.

Comment: It was simply a comment, that is all. Just like this one! ;)

Comment: @Moo You do bring up a common concern as SU is still in beta. I do like the suggestion of sending the password to any author that has had a question moved to SU. That would make it much more accessible to any question migrated to SU. However, no matter what status SU is in, questions that not appropriate for SO or SF are simply that. Do not worry though, you are not alone in your concern and do bring up valid points. This is why SU is coming soon to a internet connection near you.

Comment: @Moo Also, meta is the correct place to ask these kind of concerns/suggestions.  Keep in mind though, people are much more relaxed and prone to post entertaining comments on meta. We are all upvote and downvotes fanatics here also.

Answer (score 8):

I really think the original submitter should be given the beta password somehow. Perhaps have links from migrated questions pass through an intermediate page that sets the password cookie for the user (optionally with a top bar notice).

Comment: This isn't a bad idea actually.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, regardless of whether SU exists or not, your question wasn't suitable for SO.  Luckily for you, SU *does* exist, so your question doesn't just get closed as not programming related and deleted in short order.

Second, SU's password is not a big secret by any stretch.  Look, I'll post [a link to it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/).  And even if it *were*, it won't always be in beta.  Eventually someone else will have the same question (probably you if you couldn't get into the beta), and need that same answer.  Luckily, it will already exist on SU.

Comment: It wasn't my question, just one I was going to offer an answer for.

Comment: Some moderator needs to copy this answer and just auto-post it to this question every time it gets asked. Then close it and move it to SU...

Comment: @Shog9: I'm pretty sure you missed the step where somebody links to Welbog.

Comment: Welbog needs to be a moderator, then he can just link to himself linking to you linking to him. It'd save everyone a lot of time (except Welbog).

Answer (score 4):

SuperUser is in closed beta only so far as that it is closed to people who can't check the blog to find the password to it or ask someone for the password that's already in. This is a **really** **really** easy barrier of entry to overcome.

Comment: Yeah, its really really easy - if you knew there was a blog, and that the SU password resided in it somewhere.

So why isn't that advertised in any of the closure threads?  It seems very much like its left hanging to the casual SO/SF user.

Comment: Have you ever thought to try searching for "superuser password"? You made it to this site, it would have sounded like a logical thing to do.

Comment: No, I didn't - because the welcome page makes it look like a closed, invite only beta.  If it were made a bit clearer on that page, then I would have.  Why would I be seeking the password if I hadn't been invited in the first place?

Comment: Because there were no invitations

Comment: Moo is right, to anyone not familiar with the system won't know where to find the password, and the SU login page looks like there *were* invitations, and you can't get in without one. Someone who doesn't know about the blog, doesn't know there weren't invitations.

Answer (score 4):

Besides, look at the related links of this question:

### Related

- wrongly tagged “belongs-on-superuser”?
- How to access superuser.com?
- Moving to super user while it’s still on beta?
- Is the superuser beta invite-only?
- Change the superuser.com link in the footer to say “(private beta)” until it’s open to all.
- Do we really need a beta period for SuperUser?
- When Super User Will Be Open
- Serverfault down? How to get into superuser beta?

Comment: At a glance, none of those really address the point he is making here.

Comment: He asked how to access http://Superuser.com

Answer (score 3):

I think you do have a point. While the password is easy to find *if you know where to look*, a lot of people don't keep up with the SO blog.

However it either move it to a beta site where the questioner **may not** be able to access it, or, as Pesto pointed out, delete it from SO, in which case **no one** will be able to access it.